# How do I create a .jar with JavaFX embedded?

Tags: java, jar, javafx

I have a complete simulation with added animation and graphing functionality that I would like to package as an application. When I "Clean and Build" in Netbeans, I get the JAR and the program runs fine, but the JavaFX component (the graphs) never show up like they do when I run the program in Netbeans. How do I package the JavaFX library or what should I do to include this functionality in my JAR?

Answer (score 0):

you should include your jfxrt.jar with creating jar. It contains the run time for javafx

this inside your jre